# "Invalid UUID string" when editing bitstream in DSpace6

Tags: dspace

I'm experimenting with DSpace 6 (rc3-snapshot, XMLUI) and everything seems to work except bitstream editing. If I try to set embargo to a bitstream, for example, this UUID error always pops up. It does not matter if I create item in a clean install or if I convert data from existing database.

Is this a DSpace issue, java issue or postgres issue? Any help is appreciated.

JAVA: `openjdk version "1.8.0_91"`

TOMCAT: tomcat-7.0.54

DB:  postgres -V

```
postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.5.3
```

OS: centos/debian

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid UUID string: 3
    at java.util.UUID.fromString(UUID.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:155)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:243)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:3237)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:2394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:162)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:393)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2834)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:160)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:538)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.callMethod(ScriptableObject.java:1833)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptableObject.callMethod(ScriptableObject.java:1803)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.flow.javascript.fom.FOM_JavaScriptInterpreter.handleContinuation(FOM_JavaScriptInterpreter.java:698)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.CallFunctionNode.invoke(CallFunctionNode.java:94)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.SelectNode.invoke(SelectNode.java:82)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.buildPipeline(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.buildPipeline(TreeProcessor.java:260)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:107)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.SelectNode.invoke(SelectNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.buildPipeline(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.buildPipeline(TreeProcessor.java:260)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:107)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.buildPipeline(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:186)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.buildPipeline(TreeProcessor.java:260)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:277)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.AspectGenerator.setup(AspectGenerator.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.prepareInternal(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:480)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor114.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.prepareInternal(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.init(SitemapSource.java:292)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSource.<init>(SitemapSource.java:148)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.impl.SitemapSourceFactory.getSource(SitemapSourceFactory.java:62)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:153)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.source.CocoonSourceResolver.resolveURI(CocoonSourceResolver.java:183)
    at org.apache.cocoon.generation.FileGenerator.setup(FileGenerator.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor61.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy203.setup(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:343)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.impl.AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.setupPipeline(AbstractCachingProcessingPipeline.java:710)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.preparePipeline(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:466)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.pipeline.AbstractProcessingPipeline.process(AbstractProcessingPipeline.java:411)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor121.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cocoon.core.container.spring.avalon.PoolableProxyHandler.invoke(PoolableProxyHandler.java:71)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy202.process(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.SerializeNode.invoke(SerializeNode.java:147)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:247)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:55)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MatchNode.invoke(MatchNode.java:87)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:247)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.MountNode.invoke(MountNode.java:117)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelineNode.invoke(PipelineNode.java:143)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.AbstractParentProcessingNode.invokeNodes(AbstractParentProcessingNode.java:78)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.sitemap.PipelinesNode.invoke(PipelinesNode.java:81)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:239)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.ConcreteTreeProcessor.process(ConcreteTreeProcessor.java:171)
    at org.apache.cocoon.components.treeprocessor.TreeProcessor.process(TreeProcessor.java:247)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:351)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servlet.RequestProcessor.service(RequestProcessor.java:169)
    at org.apache.cocoon.sitemap.SitemapServlet.service(SitemapServlet.java:84)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servletservice.ServletServiceContext$PathDispatcher.forward(ServletServiceContext.java:468)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servletservice.ServletServiceContext$PathDispatcher.forward(ServletServiceContext.java:443)
    at org.apache.cocoon.servletservice.spring.ServletFactoryBean$ServiceInterceptor.invoke(ServletFactoryBean.java:264)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy199.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.dspace.springmvc.CocoonView.render(CocoonView.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1216)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1001)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:867)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:951)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:853)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.DSpaceCocoonServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceCocoonServletFilter.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.app.xmlui.cocoon.servlet.multipart.DSpaceMultipartFilter.doFilter(DSpaceMultipartFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.dspace.utils.servlet.DSpaceWebappServletFilter.doFilter(DSpaceWebappServletFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in the DSpace 6.0 Release Candidates: https://jira.duraspace.org/browse/DS-3199

It will be fixed prior to the 6.0 final release.